# Addnig text to restricted cubic splines plot

Tags: r, spline

I have the following hypothetical data to plot restricted cubic splines

```
library(rms)
library(survival)
n <- 1000
set.seed(731)
age <- 50 + 12*rnorm(n)
label(age) <- "Age"
sex <- factor(sample(c('Male','Female'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.6, .4)))
cens <- 15*runif(n)
h <- .02*exp(.04*(age-50)+.8*(sex=='Female'))
dt <- -log(runif(n))/h
label(dt) <- 'Follow-up Time'
e <- ifelse(dt <= cens,1,0)
dt <- pmin(dt, cens)
units(dt) <- "Year"
dd <- datadist(age, sex)
options(datadist='dd')
S <- Surv(dt,e)

f <- cph(S ~ rcs(age,4) + sex, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
cox.zph(f, "rank")             # tests of PH
anova(f)
plot(Predict(f, age, sex)) # plot age effect, 2 curves for 2 sexes
```

Wit the above data, I get this fine plot:
[image]

I would like to add following text to it `text(60,-1,"p < 0.001")` but it does not work and gives me the following error message: `plot.new has not been called yet`. Any thoughts what may be the problem? Any other way I can add text (or a legend) to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rms` package moved to the lattice plotting platform. You would need to add the text in a panel call or one of the supplemental lattice functions. See `?llines` or use `trellis.focus`.

```
[![ap <- function(...) { ltext(60, 1, "p < 0.001") }

plot(Predict(f, age, sex), addpanel=ap)][1]][1]
```